# Using Google Cloud Platform to store credit card data

Tags: pci-dss, oauth, storage

I have made an iPhone app for users to book hotel rooms. A third party provides the service for booking the hotel rooms and charging the credit cards. At the moment, my app makes no attempt to save credit card information. It simply sends the credit card info to the third party provider when the user wishes to book a room. But I would like to save the credit card info so that the user doesn't have to repeatedly type it in.

Google Cloud Platform recently achieved PCI-DSS compliance. So I'm wondering if it is prudent to store my users' credit card data there? Would I need to effect additional measures to secure the data? Also, is it prudent to authenticate the iPhone app user with OAuth rather than Basic Authentication?

Comment: do you want to store a tokenized version of the card (i.e. something you get back from your payment provider), or the actual card number + expiry etc?

Comment: Unfortunately the payment provider doesn't return a tokenized version of the card [link](http://developer.ean.com/docs/book-reservation/) so I think my only choice is to store the actual card number + expiry + etc

Comment: Why not store the credit card data on the user's device?

Comment: My first thought was to store the credit card data on the iOS device. But I was advised by many knowledgeable individuals that this is a very bad idea. I'm open to suggestions for going that route but it doesn't seem like a good option at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's not because you are using a platform which has been cleared for being PCI-DSS compliant in a single or several instances that you are also automatically PCI compliant. You will also need to go through all checks like regular ASV scanning, etc...

Note that there are certain [pieces of information which you are simply not allowed](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf) to store if you want to be PCI-DSS compliant.

PCI is all about discouraging the storage of cardholder information, so if you are just doing it for the sake of convenience, I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I appreciate the information. Regarding the "sake of convenience" point, it's a very good point but I think most merchants store credit card data for this reason. It's just my opinion but I think many users will reject an app that requires them to repeatedly type their credit card information.

Comment: Of course, but you need to decide for yourself if you can do all the hassle in a cost-effective way.

Comment: I agree. That's what led me to this question. If I can store the credit card data in Google Cloud without adding too much additional security, then it wouldn't be too much extra work. Of course there's the hassle of annual PCI checks. But my bigger concern is risk of data breach. So the question boils down to "How securely can I store data in Google Cloud?"

Comment: You could do that with encrypting the card with a client secret (e.g. their password). That way it's only present in its encrypted form in the cloud and can only be decrypted after a user gives a valid password locally.

Comment: I would be wary of that idea for the reason that if a hacker hacks a user's password, then they can decrypt their credit card data. The user's password is especially susceptible to being hacked because it resides on every machine on which the user uses Google or Facebook or whoever the Authorization server is.

Comment: Forgot you were using oauth :p

Comment: Still it's an idea worth exploring. I guess I could hash the user's information someway and then use that.

Comment: Take a look at a service like spreedly.com, you can send the cc data there directly and if you need to store it long term use their vault, you get a token back which you can use later. Spreedly will send the CC data directly to the third party. Avoid touching the CC data, PCI is a slippery slope and it's easy to underestimate it!